# how to maintian the EF connection string at one place?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following in my project solution,am trying to maintain the Database connection of Entity framework at one place so that if I have to switch the database to a different vendor(like MYSQL to MSSQL or vice-versa) I can just change the connection name at one place and doesn't have to change at all the places...I tried the following structure but running into an error,how to fix it?

Project#1

```
Dashboard.EntityFramework
-->bitDbConnection.cs


using


namespace Dashboard.EntityFramework
{
    public class bitDbConnection
    {
        BitDatabaseEntities bitDB = new BitDatabaseEntities();
    }
}
```

Project#2

```
Dashboard.Repository
-->Repository.cs

using Dashboard.EntityFramework
when I try use to bitDB variable I can the below error
```

Error:-

```
The name bitDB does not exist in current context
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't what you want but to get your code to work, write it like this:

```
namespace Dashboard.EntityFramework
{
    public class bitDbConnection
    {
        public BitDatabaseEntities bitDB = new BitDatabaseEntities();
    }
}

using Dashboard.EntityFramework
public class Repository
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var bitDB = new bitDbConnection().bitDB;

    }
}
```

So, first make bitDB field public, and then use it...

edit for question in comments:

```
public class Repository
{
    private BitDatabaseEntities bitDB = new BitDatabaseEntities().bitDB;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var x = bitDB.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: M - is there a way to declare `var bitDB = new bitDbConnection().bitDB;` outside the function and within the class `class Repository`

Comment: Marko - is there a way to declare `var bitDB` outside the function and inside the class so that any function inside the class can use it..

Comment: Marko M - with the edited answer ,the connection string is no more at one place,right?if I define a new class,I have to define the bitDB for every class right?why cant we maintain the connection in one file and then define it within the class scope?is there something in C# that prevents this?

Comment: Your is not specific enough so i can't provide adequate answer. Even my first answer  is just solution for "The name bitDB does not exist in current context", but that stuff has nothing to do with connection strings...

Comment: I work on many projects where connection string is defined in a config file and use elsewhere without problems, but as I said, your question is too broad. Try to add better examples or your problem and it will probably be solved. Good luck.

Comment: M - Let me retry ,my question is simple I want to maintain the DB entity connection @ `BitDatabaseEntities bitDB = new BitDatabaseEntities();` in one file and reuse the variable which is `bitDB` for the rest of my project,in any class and in any function without declaring it again,in the first example you provided I need to declare `bitDB` in every function ,in the second edited example I need to declare in every new class..I don't want to declare at multiple places rather reuse `bitDB` in my classes and functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137485/discussion-between-marko-m-and-user2125827).